# Property inheritance through TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I have window, where I set some property

```
<Window Foreground="White" ...
```

Now all my children get that property inherited, right? Like this

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <Label> <-- has Foreground="White" without need to explicitly specify it -->
        ...
```

However, once I use `TabControl`, inheritance is broken.

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem>
                <Grid>
                    <Label> <-- doesn't inherit Foreground property from Window -->
```

I can't set `Foreground` for `TabControl`, perhaps this is the reason. Question is why and what to do? I can use styles, but is there other, more obvious and less *code-ish* way?

Comment: Controls don't inherit properties only DataContext and Styles. You can check it up with [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) (in your example `Label`'s foreground is actually black)

Comment: I mean [`property value inheritance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197.aspx). Really hate myself for saying things wrong at first.

Comment: @TzahMama, that is incorrect. Certainly, some controls such as container controls and text based do inherit property values. `DependencyProperty` property value inheritance would be pretty pointless otherwise, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Sheridan, I wasn't familiar with the concept of property value inheritance. Looking it up now, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

There's really not much that you can do in this case. The property value inheritance is definitely stopping at the `TabControl`. I suspect that it has something to do with all of the different `Template`s and `Style`s that the `TabItem` provides (although that shouldn't cause any problem really).

As you said, the only way to set the `Foreground` properties of multiple controls inside the `TabControl` is to use a `Style`. However, there *is* a way to set the `Foreground` property on controls that don't have their own `Foreground` property. That is to use the `TextElement.Foreground` Attached Property:

```
<Grid TextElement.Foreground="Red">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Hey what colour am I?" />
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Header" TextElement.Foreground="Red" />
        </TabControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Of course, the `TabItem` control *does* have a `Foreground` property, so this is not a great example... it works better on a `Grid` full of `TextBlock`s. You should note though, that setting `TextElement.Foreground` Attached Property will not have any effect on a control that has no `TextElement` in it. (`TextBlock` controls contain `TextElement`s). You can also call `TextBlock.Foreground`.

Comment: It took me some time to go through. I can set `TextElement.Foreground` (or `TextBlock.Foreground`, which is more like I need) to a `TabControl`, but it does nothing to a `TextBlock` color inside `TabItem`. It only works if I set it for `TabItem` (and as there are multiple items with text inside - it will be pretty WET solution). Bad thing is what said inheritance doesn't seems to work with `Label` or `Button`. And there is no `Button.Foreground` to be attached to a parent either.

Comment: I don't understand your problem... you said that you could set the `Foreground` property in a `Style`, so where's the problem? My post was really just to agree with your findings and to introduce the `TextElement.Foreground` Attached Property... I *did* say as much in my answer.

Comment: Your answer is helpful. Though it doesn't seems to solve the issue of inheritance problem in any way: `TabControl` in the chain `Window`->`TextBlock`(is working), but `Window`->`TabControl`->...->`TextBlock`(does not). Do you mean binding (to pass `TextElement.Foreground` from parent to child and then further)? Or how can I use attached properties to pass `Foreground` value through `TabControl`? In you example you setting it again for `TabItem`. So why is there `Grid` with attached property on higher level?

Comment: I AM AGREEING WITH YOU. Property Value Inheritance doesn't work through the `TabControl`. There is NO SOLUTION to this. USE A `Style` INSTEAD. Is that clearer?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why inheritance has no effect here is [dependency property value precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
Inherited values have almost the lowest precedence; they will be overriden by the default style for the label (which assigns a black value to the foreground color).

In your second code snippet, you write that the `Label` inside the `Grid` has white foreground; this is probably because you have applied a style to that label, or because your operating system's default foreground color is white. In any case, this `Label` definitely does not inherit its white color from the window, if it is an unstyled `Label` control.

Therefore, you have to add a style to your `Window`.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, it doesn't work for label. But it does for `TextBlock`. For some reasons when asking question I say `Label` (my brains work totally without my control anymore).